# Creating a drop down list with kentico using custom css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, kentico

I have html template I'm converting to a kentico template. The challenge is making a drop down list that will conform to the css and javascript design. I already tried doing that with drop down' in 'Listing and viewing' without success.

This is the idea:

```
      <ul class="drop_down">
         <li>Item 1</li>
         <li>Item 2</li>
         <li>Item 3</li>
         <li>Item 4</li>
      </ul>
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: What does 'ul' tag have to do with drop down list? Be more specific, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CSS List Menu web part, which generates the exact HTML structure you provided, minus the class name, but you can use the CSS prefix field in the web part properties under the "Design" section and enter your class name there.

Comment: This will be fine but my challenge is how to set the design parameters. say for instance, my ul has a class="drop_down".

Comment: You can use the "CSS Prefix" field under "Design" of the CSS List Menu Web Part properties. This will add a class name to the UL. You can also use the generated ID and class by Kentico and follow this article to accomplish a simple drop down menu in Kentico.

http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: What if I have the ul having each li with different class?

Comment: If you go to "Properties > Navigation (or Menu)" of the Document, you can set a "Document Menu Class", which will render out in the LI.